# How to get training accuracy in svmlight with cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, svm, cross-validation, svmlight

I want to run cross validation on my training set using SVMlight. It seems that the option for this is -x 1 (although I'm not sure how many folds it implements...). The output is:

```
XiAlpha-estimate of the error: error<=31.76% (rho=1.00,depth=0)
XiAlpha-estimate of the recall: recall=>68.24% (rho=1.00,depth=0)
XiAlpha-estimate of the precision: precision=>69.02% (rho=1.00,depth=0)
Number of kernel evaluations: 56733
Computing leave-one-out **lots of gibberish here**
Retrain on full problem..............done.
Leave-one-out estimate of the error: error=12.46%
Leave-one-out estimate of the recall: recall=86.39%
Leave-one-out estimate of the precision: precision=88.82%
Actual leave-one-outs computed:  412 (rho=1.00)
Runtime for leave-one-out in cpu-seconds: 0.84
```

How can I get the accuracy? From the `estimate of the error`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

These are contradicting concepts. Training error is the error **on the training set**, while cross validation is used to approximate the **validation error** (on the data **not** used for training).

Your output suggests that you are using N-folds (where N-size of the training set) which leads to so called "leave one out" validation (only 1 testing point!) which is overestimating your model's quality. You should try 10-folds, and your accuracy is simply 1-error.

Comment: Thank you @lejlot, but I'm afraid I didn't understand you. 1. Cross validation is not used on training data? (Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#K-fold_cross-validation) incorrect?) 2. I didn't understand the second part of your answer - I didn't see how I could decide how many folds  to use, and why is it overestimating the model's quality, and what is 1-error... I really apologize... if you could please explain some more I'd really really appreciate it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Training data is the data used for **training** as name suggests. While cross validation splits your data into training and testing, former is never seen during the training phase. You have written "training accuracy" - this is wrong, not the sentence about using the data for CV. Training accuracy is **not** measured by CV.

"1-error" means "substract error value from 1 and you get accuracy". 

Finally - leave one out "overestimates" in the sense that it returns much higher accuracy than it should. The "reasonable" number of folds is 10 (often used in such cases).

Comment: Ah... now I get you better @lejlot, thanks, but - IMHO, I thought that cross validation is used for testing purposes during the _training_ phase, isn't it? And as to what you say about using 10 folds - I agree, but leave-one-out estimates are (I think) the only form of cross validation that svmlight allows.

Comment: You are still confusing terms. "Training error" is not "error computed during training phase" but "error **on the training set**". This is completely different than cv based estimation of error on **validation** set.

Comment: Apologies if I've missed it, but how do you specify the number of folds for leave-one-out cross validation in the training set using svmlight? -x can be 0 or 1, so is there another parameter?